# Gcc refuses to use SSE instruction set for math in 32-bit x86 mode

Tags: gcc, x86, sse

I have a third-party library that seems to work incorrectly when using x87 for math (which is default in 32 bit mode) but works in 64 bit mode (where SSE is default). I was trying to recompile it using SSE floating model, but surprisingly GCC (Debian 4.9.2-10) gave me a warning

> warning: SSE instruction set disabled, using 387 arithmetics

which was not what I wanted. Googling on that warning gives a bunch of outdated threads.

The minimum example producing this warning is

```
echo 'main(){}' | gcc -x c -m32 -mfpmath=sse -
```

Am I missing some flag? Do I need to rebuild gcc with SSE support?

Comment: docs say "For the i386 compiler, you need to use -march=cpu-type, -msse or -msse2 switches to enable SSE extensions and make this option effective"

Comment: Thank you, the -msse2 solved the problem.